# Apply function to every matrix of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I would like to apply a function to each of the 3x3 matrices in my (6890,6890,3,3) numpy array. Until now, I have tried using vectorization on a smaller example and with a simpler function which didn't work out.

```
def myfunc(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x)

m = np.arange(45).reshape(5,3,3)
t = m.shape[0]
r = np.zeros((t, t))

q = m[:,None,...] @ m.swapaxes(1,2) # m[i] @ m[j].T
f = np.vectorize(q, otypes=[np.float])
res = myfunc(f)
```

Is vectorization even the right approach to solve this problem efficiently or should I try something else? I've also looked into `numpy.apply_along_axis` but this only applies to 1D-subarrays.

Comment: Is the listed `myfunc` the actual function that you are working with?

Comment: No, it isn't. This is the actual one: `pyquaternion.Quaternion.log(pyquaternion.Quaternion(matrix=m)).norm`

Comment: If your function can only work with the 3x3 array, there's no way around calling it 6890*6890 times.

Comment: np.vectorize will be hard to apply, annd is slower.   `apply_along isn't any easier.

Comment: @hpaulj This means that I have to use for-loops?

Comment: `np.vectorize` has a note saying it doesn't promise any speedup.  Also it normally passes scalar elements to your function, where as you want to pass 2d elements.  It has a `signature` mode that can do that, but that's even slower.

Answer (score 1):

You need loop over each element and apply function:

```
import numpy as np

# setup function
def myfunc(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x*2)

# setup data array
data = np.arange(45).reshape(5, 3, 3)

# loop over elements and update
for item in np.nditer(data, op_flags = ['readwrite']):
    item[...] = myfunc(item)
```

If you need apply function for entire 3x3 array then use:

```
out_data = []
for item in data:
    out_data.append(myfunc(item))
```

Output:

```
[14.2828568570857, 39.761790704142086, 66.4529909033446, 93.32202312423365, 120.24974012445931]
```

Comment: If I wanted to apply the function to all the 6890*6890 3x3 matrices in my actual (6890,6890,3,3) array would I have to introduce a nested for-loop (with 6890*6890 iterations)? Because this is exactly what I want to avoid as it's way too slow.